# Add file to an already existing VM with terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

How can I add local files to an already existing VM instance? I tried with adding a file provisioner block to the resource like this:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" { 
#other code
provisioner "file" {
    source = "${path.module}/set_time_style.sh"
    destination = "/etc/profile.d/set_time_style.sh"
  }
#other code
}
```

But after running terraform plan, the change is not detected. I read somewhere, that it is intended, that provisioner related changes are not detected. But how could I achive my goal then with terraform?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terraform, How to run the provisioner on existing resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37865979/terraform-how-to-run-the-provisioner-on-existing-resources)

Comment: It answers my question, but it is not the type of question I wanted to hear. :) It looks like a hack to me. I would expect to have a similar kind of functionality from terraform. But I also can understand, that this would be against the philosophy behind it. So...whatever...anyway, thanks for the link

Comment: I get a feeling that is what ansible is for: https://www.ansible.com/

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can use "null_resource" in Terraform to achieve this, its not the best way to do it as I feel that this is not Terraform's purpose. Terraform is used mostly for resource provisioning.

Once the VM is provisioned, additional management within the VM like files, softwares etc. should be managed by a configuration management software like Chef or Ansible. These tools have better ways to handle such requirements as they are designed for similar purposes.

Have seen a couple of organizations implementing the same design pattern due the reasons mentioned above.

Anyway, if you still need to do it via Terraform, I think its possible by using the "null resource" in the following way.

```
resource "null_resource" "copy_file_after" {
 provisioner "file" {
    source      = "dummy.txt"
    destination = "/tmp/dummy.txt"

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "user"
      private_key = file("path_to_key")
      host        = host
    }
  }
```