# How can I use Terraform's file provisioner to copy from my local machine onto a VM?

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm new to Terraform and have so far managed to get a basic VM (plus Resource Manager trimmings) up and running on Azure. The next task I have in mind is to have Terraform copy a file from my local machine into the newly created instance. Ideally I'm after a solution where the file will be copied each time the apply command is run.

I feel like I'm pretty close but so far I just get endless "Still creating..." statements once I apply (the file is 0kb so after a couple of mins it feels safe to give up).

So far, this is what I've got (based on this code): https://stackoverflow.com/a/37866044/4941009

**Network**

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "pub-ip" {
    name = "PublicIp"
    location = "${var.location}"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    public_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    domain_name_label = "${var.hostname}"
}
```

**VM**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name                  = "${var.hostname}"
  location              = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  vm_size               = "${var.vm_size}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.nic.id}"]

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "${var.image_publisher}"
    offer     = "${var.image_offer}"
    sku       = "${var.image_sku}"
    version   = "${var.image_version}"
  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name          = "${var.hostname}osdisk1"
    vhd_uri       = "${azurerm_storage_account.stor.primary_blob_endpoint}${azurerm_storage_container.cont.name}/${var.hostname}osdisk.vhd"
    os_type       = "${var.os_type}"
    caching       = "ReadWrite"
    create_option = "FromImage"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "${var.hostname}"
    admin_username = "${var.admin_username}"
    admin_password = "${var.admin_password}"
  }

  os_profile_windows_config {
    provision_vm_agent = true
  }

  boot_diagnostics {
    enabled     = true
    storage_uri = "${azurerm_storage_account.stor.primary_blob_endpoint}"
  }

  tags {
      environment = "${var.environment}"
  }
}
```

**File Provisioner**

```
resource "null_resource" "copy-test-file" {

  connection {
    type     = "ssh"
    host     = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.ip_address}"
    user     = "${var.admin_username}"
    password = "${var.admin_password}"
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "test.txt"
    destination = "/tmp/test.txt"
  }

}
```

As an aside, if I pass incorrect login details to the provisioner (ie rerun this after the VM has already been created and supply a different password to the provisioner) the behaviour is the same. Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a bug...

Comment: `terraform` is used for creating infrastructure. I feel that if you want to provision your machine you should look into `ansible`.

Comment: Yeah, I mean I agree that Terraform isn't the best for configuration but I just need to copy one file and it feels like it's probably overkill to use a whole different product just for that. Plus it'd be nice to sort the whole thing out with a single script.

Comment: what do the logs say when running with debugging enbaled? I mean, running like this: TF_LOG=DEBUG terraform apply

Comment: For anyone else having trouble with this, I have posted a workaround that does not require using file provisioners: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631004

Comment: In case it helps, I am using [cloud-config](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html), and there you can use [write_files](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#write-files) with `b64` encoding. You can use the `base64encode` function available in Terraform.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I eventually got this working. Honestly, I kind of forgot about this question so I can't remember what my exact issue was, the example below though seems to work on my instance:

```
resource "null_resource" remoteExecProvisionerWFolder {

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "test.txt"
    destination = "/tmp/test.txt"
  }

  connection {
    host     = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.ip_address}"
    type     = "ssh"
    user     = "${var.admin_username}"
    password = "${var.admin_password}"
    agent    = "false"
  }
}
```

So it looks like the only difference here is the addition of `agent = "false"`. This would make some sense as there's only one SSH authentication agent for windows and it's probable I hadn't explicitly specified to use that agent before. However it could well be that I ultimately changed something elsewhere in the configuration. Sorry future people for not being much help on this one.

Answer (score 6):

FYI, windows instances you can connect via type winrm

```
resource "null_resource" "provision_web" {

  connection {
    host     = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.ip_address}"
    type     = "winrm"
    user     = "alex"
    password = "alexiscool1!"
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "path/to/folder"
    destination = "C:/path/to/destination"
  }

}
```