# Error while using Terraform provisioner file for GCP Windows VM

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a File in Local and want to copy that file in newly created Windows VM in GCP via Terraform.

That VM is created Successfully but it doesn't copy file in VM.

I have tried many way, but don't know where I am doing wrong.

First I tried with in resource block.
example:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "vm_instance2" {
   name         = "instance1"
   machine_type = "n1-standard-4"
   zone         = "europe-west2-a"
   tags         =  ["web"]
   boot_disk {
      initialize_params {
         image = "abcd"
         size = "100"
         type = "pd-standard"
      }
   }
   network_interface {
       subnetwork  = google_compute_subnetwork.gcp_subnet2.name
       access_config {}
   }
   provisioner "file" {
     source = "test"
     destination = "C:/"

     connection {
       type     = "winrm"
       port    = "5985"
       user     = "UserName"
       password = "Password"
       timeout  = "60s"
       host     =  google_compute_instance.vm_instance2.network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip
   }
 }
 }
```

But it not working so I tried with "null_resource" but it also not working.

```
resource "null_resource" "provision_config" {
provisioner "file" {
source = "test"
destination = "C:/"

connection {
  type     = "winrm"
  port    = "5985"
  user     = "UserName"
  password = "pass@123"
  timeout  = "30s"
  host     =  google_compute_instance.vm_instance2.network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip
}
}
}
```

I don't find where I am doing wrong.

Comment: I am facing Error: timeout - last error: http response error: 401 - invalid content type

Comment: Could you check if replacing the source location "test" with absolute path makes a difference? See this other [StackOverflow's Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567881/how-can-i-use-terraforms-file-provisioner-to-copy-from-my-local-machine-onto-a)

Comment: @Pedro Thanks for your opinion, I have checked that also with absolute path but It also not working

Comment: Please could you also check why on the top of the code resource "vm_instance2" is different than name "instance1"?

Answer (score 0):

Looks similar to this [Github's issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/9003#issuecomment-611170671). It seems that the Windows Image requires SSL, meaning you need to set

```
"winrm_use_ssl": true
```

as well as having the certificate, that it could be self-signed if you don't have one, adding the "winrm_insecure" for skip checking the certification authenticity.